# Why use AWS AppSync client on top of vue-apollo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-appsync, vue-apollo, appsync-apollo-client

When using AWS AppSync as a backend GraphQL server, what are the advantages of using AppSync client on top of vue-apollo client? Can I just use vue-apollo to interact with my GraphQl server without using AppSync client?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the specific use-cases or features looking for?

AppSync provides lot of the other features like real-time subscriptions, offline access, caching and enterprise security and fine-grained access control.